# Why does this suggested solution prefer a different way of calculating percentages based on aggregations?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, optimization, aggregate

I'm working through a problem set from CMU's public db systems course. I have the following two tables:

**Order**

| Id | CustomerId | EmployeeId | OrderDate | RequiredDate | ShippedDate | ShipVia | Freight | ShipName | ShipAddress | ShipCity | ShipRegion | ShipPostalCode | ShipCountry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10248 | VINET | 5 | 2012-07-04 | 2012-08-01 | 2012-07-16 | 3 | 16.75 | Vins et alcools Chevalier | 59 rue de l'Abbaye | Reims | Western Europe | 51100 | France |
| 10249 | TOMSP | 6 | 2012-07-05 | 2012-08-16 | 2012-07-10 | 1 | 22.25 | Toms Spezialitäten | Luisenstr. 48 | Münster | Western Europe | 44087 | Germany |

**Shipper**

| Id | CompanyName | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Speedy Express | (503) 555-9831 |
| 2 | United Package | (503) 555-3199 |

The question I am attempting to answer is the following:

> For each Shipper, find the percentage of orders which are late.
> Details: An order is considered late if ShippedDate > RequiredDate.
> Print the following format, order by descending percentage,  rounded
> to the nearest hundredths, like `United Package|23.44`.

This is the query I came up with, which produces the expected results:

```
SELECT 
    CompanyName, 
    ROUND(100*SUM(IIF(ShippedDate > RequiredDate, 1, 0))/Cast(Count(ShipName) as Float), 2) as percent 
FROM 'Order' AS O 
JOIN Shipper AS S 
ON O.ShipVia = S.Id 
GROUP BY CompanyName 
ORDER BY percent DESC;
```

The official solution is a more involved query as follows:

```
SELECT CompanyName, round(delayCnt * 100.0 / cnt, 2) AS pct
FROM (
      SELECT ShipVia, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
      FROM 'Order'
      GROUP BY ShipVia
     ) AS totalCnt
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ShipVia, COUNT(*) AS delaycnt 
            FROM 'Order'
            WHERE ShippedDate > RequiredDate 
            GROUP BY ShipVia
           ) AS delayCnt
          ON totalCnt.ShipVia = delayCnt.ShipVia
INNER JOIN Shipper on totalCnt.ShipVia = Shipper.Id
ORDER BY pct DESC;
```

The outputs of the two queries match, each returning the following:

```
Federal Shipping|23.61
Speedy Express|23.46
United Package|23.44
```

What is the benefit of doing it as shown in the solution rather than using my approach?

Comment: Please remove the external like and include the minimal explanation of the problem.

Comment: You got a rather interesting question here. I tried to figure out when your query will provide a different result in this given use case. So far, I haven’t found any, although I am not a SQL crack, so maybe some others can chip in. To me, the aggregate functions with GROUP BY work as expected. As you mentioned this is part of a course, another way to look at it is what is the purpose of this exercise within the scope of the course (e.g. applying nested queries?) and whether the IIF is considered available for use or not at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official solution is a very bad solution because it aggregates twice on the same table `Order` and then joins the results whilst the same can be achieved by a single aggregation query (like your first query).

I can't believe that this would be proposed as a proper solution for this type of problems.
I hope it's just for practice on joins for subqueries.

Also, I find it very disappointing to see the use of single quotes for table (or column) names/aliases.
This is a very bad practice an it can lead to unexpected results.
When needed use double quotes which is the SQL standard (square brackets or backticks also work in SQLite).

As I said your first query is correct and it could be further simplified with the use of the aggregate function `AVG()`:

```
SELECT S.CompanyName, 
       ROUND(100*AVG(COALESCE(O.ShippedDate, '') > O.RequiredDate), 2) AS percent
FROM Shipper AS S JOIN "Order" AS O 
ON O.ShipVia = S.Id 
GROUP BY S.Id 
ORDER BY percent DESC;
```

Note the use of `Id` (it is the primary key of `Shipper`) in the `GROUP BY` clause instead of `CompanyName`, which provides better performance.

Also, I used `COALESCE()`, because I found (after downloading your database) that in the column `ShippedDate` there are `null`s.

Comment: Agreed.  Additionally, the official solution doesn't show cases where no shipments for this shipper are found.  It might not produce (as the requirement states) "for each shipper".  An outer join to address this would help.  Andrew's answer is better (than the official answer), but seems to assume CompanyName is unique, which doesn't seem to be guaranteed by the given detail. For this reason also, `GROUP BY ShipVia` would be best, given the current known detail.

Comment: @JonArmstrong I have downloaded the database from https://15445.courses.cs.cmu.edu/fall2020/homework1/ and I found that CompanyName is not defined as unique (although there are no duplicate names).